# Is TArray<T>.Create() documented somewhere?

Tags: arrays, delphi, generics

It was just by chance when I found out that a construct like this actually compiles and produces the desired result:

```
var
  Arr: TArray<Integer>;
begin
  Arr := TArray<Integer>.Create(100, 101, 102);
end;
```

I only tested it in Delphi XE, but it may work in older versions, too. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: It also works in Delphi 2010 and it seems to be compiler-magic. [Embarcadero documentation here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/Generics.Collections.TArray) says TArray<T> is from `Generics.Collections` but it works without including that in the uses clause; The source code in `Generics.Collections` makes no reference to any kind of constructor.

Comment: `TArray<T>` is declared in `System.pas` as `array of <T>`. `Generics.Collection` declares `TArray`, which provides some generic class methods for searching and sorting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's documented in the [language guide](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays).

Comment: While this might have been true at the time, it's not now (darn wikis!)

Comment: @jep No, it's still there today: *An alternative
method of allocating memory for dynamic arrays is to
invoke the array contructor*

Comment: Ah, okay, that's what you were referring to.  I thought you were talking about a bit more than just a short example and that line as explanation.  I suppose it's documentation, just of the most minimal sort and that doesn't actually go any further than what was stated in the question.  Fair enough, though, in that it is technically "documented".

Answer (score 13):

It's a generic version of the following, which works as far back as Delphi 2007:

```
type
  TIntArray = array of Integer;

var
  MyIntArray: TIntArray;
begin
  MyIntArray := TIntArray.Create(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
  ...
end;
```

It's finally a solution to being able to initialize an array without knowing the size first.

Comment: it's rather crippled without support for open arrays sadly

Comment: Note that Delphi 2007 one supports generics in the .NET version. In de Win32 version you have to get Delphi 2009.

Comment: @Johan: I never said anything about generics and D2007. I said the **OP's code snippet** was a generic version of the code I posted, which works in D2007. :)

Comment: you misspelled generic in the answer, got me on wrong foots.-)